# Sorting WooCommerce products by attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am recreating an ecommerce site and have run into an issue with sorting the products by a custom attribute's value. The existing site is working correctly - the products are ordered within the query arguments -

```
'meta_key' => 'pa_diameter',
'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num', 
'order'    => 'ASC',
```

This method is not working on the new site. I checked the databases of both sites and it appears that the way attribute values are stored has changed in the different versions of WooCommerce. (Old site was not updated for a while).

In the old site, the 'pa_diameter' attribute was stored as a meta key/value for each product, whereas on the new site, the value for each attibute exists only within the '_product_attributes' meta_key. Therefore I cant seem to sort by the value from within the WP_Query.

Has anyone successfully sorted by a custom attribute value in the latest version of WooCommerce?

Comment: Attributes have always been taxonomies, as far as I know.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes, if I use a tax query to only pull posts with a specific 'diameter', it works. So in that way, the attribute behaves like a taxonomy. However, when i try to order by the attribute, the query returns no results. If I swap out the meta_key for something like the price, or sku, it works. Product attributes seem to be behaving differently, and I think it has something to do with the way they are serialized in the database.

Comment: Since attributes are taxonomies, you can't "order" by them, you can only "group" by them. I'm not aware that the attributes were ever saved as meta, but I must be wrong since you report you have it in your database. Diameter seems like something that should be meta and not a taxonomy.